# How to sync two databases for disconnected systems from different companies

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, ssis

Is there a standard messaging protocol(s) / API(s) available to keep databases in sync. Or alternatively API(s) for creating and parsing messages.

Our company is working with another company to provide two different software packages to two different kinds of users. The data sits in two separate databases but parts of it have to remain in sync.

Their system is pretty much a black box to us. And vice versa.

So what would be required would be to track updates, and turn these into messages and send them to a web service, map these back to the destination database fields, and commit them.

The database schemas do not match.

I am aware that we are going to have to roll most of this ourself, but some ideas around messaging or techniques would be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers provided give me some good ideas, but I think we are going to end up doing something a bit different.

We are using MSMQ, and defining a standard messaging system which we will roll ourselves.

As to how we will know what things have changed I am not sure at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

One solution : [SQL Server Integration Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/cc511477). It appears from SQL Server 2005. This is exactly what you need. It was called DTS in SQL Server 2000 for Data Transformation Service. This was created to import/export/transform data from one point to an other. This is really easy to use from SQL Server 2005 (DTS is quite horrible).

So basically, you will have to write packages to import data from their database, transform, filter, etc. it exactly how you need it to insert it into your database. And vice versa.

Regarding the black box fact, you should generate the database relational design to make it easier.

**EDIT**
Just in case of you need to install it, I remember bugs from the SQL Server 2005 installer not installing SSIS at all. I had to satisfy all warnings in the installer system requirements step to obtain it.

Comment: What do you mean by this 'Regarding the black box fact, you should generate the database relational design to make it easier'?? Do you just mean that we should agree on a design and make them both the same. Unfortunately company politics wouldn't allow that I don't think. Both systems are in production with limited functionality at the moment.

Comment: If you have a read access to their database, you can generate the database relational schema to be able to see every tables, every relations between tables, every primary and foreign keys, every types. This would be much easier to understand how to get your data. Finally, I recently had to synchronize several different databases with a single one to store statistics and I used SSIS. It absolutely fit my needs. So if you have SQL Server 2005/2008 installed, launch SSIS and try it. This is only "graphical programming", there is no need to code a single line (only SQL).

Comment: So with SSIS, can certain activities 'trigger' data to flow. E.g. in database one I update a certain record, can that cause a trigger to send that data to database two?

Comment: Yes. You can store the package in the server and execute it, or call the execute procedure with the filename. But this would be to make "real-time" synchronization. Maybe it would be more reasonable if you schedule a complete synchronization, now it depends on your needs.

Comment: I found something much more interesting : create an sql agent with your package and start it in from your triggers. This will make the action "in background" without deteriorating your triggers performances, compared to loading an SSIS package in a trigger and executing it. By calling the agent, it should be done in a new thread, without stopping your current execution.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

- track the changes that have to be synced
- apply the changes to the peer

There is a solution that combines a solution to both issues and I'm sure you are aware of it: replication. [Merge Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152746.aspx) would allow both sites to update the data and would also provide merge conflict resolution. But replication only works when the table schema is similar and puts a big constraint on development as schema changes have to be carefully coordinated between the sites. In practice, when the sites are operated by independent companies, is quite difficult to maintain for a long term.

If you want to roll your own the change tracking part has built in support in SQL Server:

- [Change Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280462.aspx)
- [Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489.aspx)

Both can be used for a sync solution as a mean to detect *what* changed.

Applying the changes can be resolved by a web service, but there are also built-in solutions in SQL Server that allow for far higher scalability and throughput: [Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166043.aspx). Relying on a message defined API for sync allows the two sites to evolve at their own pace and change the schema almost at will, as long as the communication API (the message protocol)remains unchanged.